# Get a diff of current transaction in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Is it possible to retrieve some sort of text representation of the current transaction operations?

For example if I run two sets of queries each within their own transaction, get a snapshot of changes, then abort them both, just so I could compare differences, is that possible?

I know I can create and run queries to store whatever I'm interested in for later comparison, but if what I describe above exists as a feature, it would be vastly easier for my purposes.

Comment: You can run a `select` query within your transaction that shows the changes, and export the results to text or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

The best you can do is to identify all rows in a table that were written by the current transaction with

```
WHERE xmin = txid_current() % 4294967296
```

but you might get false positives there (from before the last transaction ID wraparound), it will scan the whole table and you won't see if the rows were inserted or updated.